# What is the difference between these facebook access tokens?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, access-token, facebook-access-token

I'm developing a FB App that can manage pages but I need to clarify this:

what is the difference between

> $page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");

and

> $aToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();

I see that they generate different tokens but I'm unsure as which one I should store in the database for offline posting, and what each does?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One retrieves a page access token :

- You use it to perform actions on behalf of the page.

The other (by default in the PHP SDK):

- Retrieves a user access token used for performing actions on behalf of the user.

The main difference here is that in order to retrieve a page's access token, you'll need to request the `manage_pages` permission from the user.

Comment: So does this mean that I can't use  `$facebook->getAccessToken();` for posting on page but only on user's wall?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with where you can or can't post. It means who you will be posting for. It could be the user posting a message or it could be the page posting a message. The access token is specific either for a page or a user.

Comment: by the way I just tested posting with each access token and  `$facebook->getAccessToken();` doesn't seem to be able to post on page. I'm uploading an image. But anyways, my issue is resolved, thanks.